# Mapping Id of an object to another custom object field

Tags: apex, custom-object

I have a page involving 5 custom objects:

```
CustomA__c, CustomB__c, CustomC__c, CustomD__c, and CustomE__c
```

And here is the relationship among these objects:

```
M-D : CustomA__c & CustomD__c 
M-D : CustomB__c & CustomC__c
M-D : CustomD__c & CustomE__c
```

The process starts on a search page using `CustomA__c` as the standardcontroller. It has a lookup field named `CustomB__c` that looks for a certain `CustomB__c` record and all its related `Customc__c` records.

A new `CustomE__c` empty field displays automatically for each selected `Customc__c` record.

On `save()` method, new `CustomA__c` , `CustomD__c`, and `CustomE__c` records will be created.

All of these are successfully inserting but I noticed that every time there are more than 1 `CustomD__c` and `CustomE__c` records are created only the last `CustomD__c` id is mapped to `CustomE__c` records. Specifically, I need to map the ids of the newly-inserted `CustomD__c` records to `CustomD__c` fields from the `CustomE__c` object.

Here's the controller:

```
public class MainController {

        private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
        public CustomA__c custARecord {get;set;}
        public CustomB__c custBqry {get;set;}
        public List<wrapper1> wrapperList1 {get;set;}
        public List<wrapper2> wrapperList2 {get;set;}
        public List<wrapper3> wrapperList3 {get;set;}
        public List<wrapper1> tempWrapper {get;set;}
        public List<CustomA__c> ca1 {get;set;}    
        public List<CustomD__c> cd1 {get;set;}
        public List<wrapper3> w3 {get;set;}
        public List<Customc__c> cc1 {get;set;}
        public CustomA__c NewCustomA {get;set;}
        public CustomD__c tempCd  {get;set;}
        public List<Customc__c> selectedCustomc = new List<Customc__c>();


        public MainController(ApexPages.StandardController con) {
            controller = con;
            wrapperList1 = new List<wrapper1>();
            wrapperList3 = new List<wrapper3>();
            custARecord = new CustomA__c();
            custBqry = new CustomB__c();
            ca1 = new List<CustomA__c>(); 
            cd1 = new List<CustomD__c>();
            w3 = new List<wrapper3>();
        }

        public void init() {

            List<Customc__c> cc1 = new List<Customc__c>(); 
            List<wrapper1> tempWrapper = new List<wrapper1>();
            List<Customc__c> selectedCustomcItems = new List<Customc__c>();

            if(custARecord.CustomB__c != null) {

                custBqry = [SELECT Id, Name FROM CustomB__c WHERE Id=:custARecord.CustomB__c];
                cc1 = getCustomcItems();

            }

            else {
                custARecord.clear();
                wrapperList1.clear();
            }

            for(Customc__c customcloop : cc1) {

                tempWrapper.add(new wrapper1(false,customcloop));
            }


            if(tempWrapper != null) {
                wrapperList1 = tempWrapper;
            }
        }

        public List<Customc__c> getCustomcItems() {

            List<Customc__c> cc1 = new List<Customc__c>();

            cc1 = [SELECT Id, CustomB__c, Field1__c, Field2__c FROM Customc__c WHERE CustomB__c =: custARecord.CustomB__c];

            return cc1;
        }

        public PageReference newMethod() {
            getSelected();
            GetSelectedCustomcItems()
            createNewCustomE();
            return null;
        }

        public PageReference getSelected() {
            selectedCustomc.clear();
            w3.clear();
            for(wrapper1 rwrap : wrapperList1) {
                if(rwrap.IsSelected == true) {
                    selectedCustomc.add(rwrap.customclist);
                }

            }    

            return null;
        }

        public List<Customc__c> GetSelectedCustomcItems() {

            return selectedCustomc;

        }

        public void createNewCustomE() {
            if(selectedCustomc.size() > 0) {

                for(Customc__c customclist : selectedCustomc) {
                    List<wrapper3> temp_customclist = new List<wrapper3>();
                    wrapper3 newRec = new wrapper3();
                    CustomE__c newCustomE = new CustomE__c();

                    newRec.ce = newCustomE;
                    newRec.index2 = temp_customclist.size();
                    temp_customclist.add(newRec);

                    for(wrapper3 rwloop : temp_customclist) {
                        w3.add(rwloop);    
                    }     
                }

            }


        }

        public PageReference save() {

            List<CustomA__c> caList = new List<CustomA__c>();
            Map<Id, CustomA__c> caMap = new Map<Id, CustomA__c>();
            List<wrapper1> caList2 = new List<wrapper1>(); 
            List<CustomD__c> cdList = new List<CustomD__c>(); 
            List<CustomE__c> ceList = new List<CustomE__c>();
            CustomA__c NewCustomA;
            CustomD__c tempCd;

            Set<Id> newIds = new Set<Id>();
            for(wrapper1 rwraploop : wrapperList1) {

                if(rwraploop.IsSelected) {

                    if(rwraploop.customclist.CustomB__c != null) {

                        NewCustomA = new CustomA__c();
                        NewCustomA.Date__c = custARecord.Date__c;
                        NewCustomA.CustomB__c = rwraploop.customclist.CustomB__c;

                        caMap.put(rwraploop.customclist.CustomB__c, NewCustomA);
                    } 


                    caList2.add(rwraploop);

                }
            }

            if(!caMap.isEmpty()) {

               insert caMap.values();

                if(caList2 != null && !caList2.IsEmpty()) {

                    List<Customc__c> newCcList = new List<Customc__c>();

                    for(wrapper1 rec1 : caList2) {      
                        newCcList.add(rec1.customclist);
                    }

                    for(Customc__c rec1 : newCcList) {

                        tempCd = new CustomD__c();

                        tempCd.Field1__c = rec1.Field1__c;
                        tempCd.Field2__c = rec1.Field2__c; 
                        tempCd.CustomA__c = caMap.values().Id;
                        tempCd.Customc__c = rec1.Id;
                        cdList.add(tempCd); 

                    }

                    if(cdList != null && !cdList.isEmpty()) {

                        insert cdList;

                    }    


                    for(wrapper3 rec2 : w3) {

                        CustomE__c ce2 = new CustomE__c();

                        ce2.Field1__c = rec2.ce.Field1__c;
                        ce2.Field2__c = rec2.ce.Field2__c;
                        ce2.CustomA__c = NewCustomA.Id;
                        ce2.CustomD__c = tempCd.Id; 
                        ceList.add(ce2); 

                    }

                    insert ceList; 



                }

                Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();

                for(CustomA__c idl : caList) {

                    ids.add(idl.Id);
                } 


                List<CustomA__c> caqry = [SELECT Id, Name, Date__c, CustomB__c FROM CustomA__c WHERE ID IN : ids];

                ca1 = caqry; 

            }

            PageReference pg = new PageReference('/' + NewCustomA.Id);
            pg.setRedirect(true);
            return pg;
        } 



        public class wrapper1 {
            public Customc__c customclist {get;set;}
            public Boolean IsSelected {get;set;}

            public wrapper1(Boolean is, Customc__c cc3) {

                IsSelected = is;
                customclist = cc3;  

            }

        } 

        public class wrapper2 {
            public CustomD__c r {get;set;}
            public Integer index {get;set;}

        }

        public class wrapper3 {
            public CustomE__c ce {get;set;}
            public Integer index2 {get;set;}
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue lays in this section of your code:

```
              for(wrapper3 rec2 : w3) {

                    CustomE__c ce2 = new CustomE__c();

                    ce2.Field1__c = rec2.ce.Field1__c;
                    ce2.Field2__c = rec2.ce.Field2__c;
                    ce2.CustomA__c = NewCustomA.Id;
                    ce2.CustomD__c = tempCd.Id; 
                    ceList.add(ce2); 

                }

                insert ceList;
```

The problem is that you need to be creating a list of CustomE__c records for each unique CustomC__c record. Once you have that, you then `put` the values into a `Map of CustomC__c.ID to list<Id> of CustomE__c` records so you can later relate the CustomD__c records to the appropriate child CustomE__c records. Your parent `tempCd.Id;` must be the same for all of those records. Your method above doesn't allow you to do that; thus the need for a map to track them.

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to best adjust your code to implement this type of mapping in your code.

**EDIT:**

Example of how to do what you need:

In your code posted above you have a section where you add the queried CustomC__c records to a wrapper that resulted from the CustomB__c record selection:

```
        for(Customc__c customcloop : cc1) {

            tempWrapper.add(new wrapper1(false,customcloop));
        }
```

This is where you also need to create a map of those results with CustomB__c. Currently, you use the method below to return `list<CustomC__c>cc1`. It's what you need to use to get what you want:

```
    public list<Customc__c> getCustomcItems() {

        list<Customc__c>cc1 = new list<Customc__c>();

        cc1 = [SELECT Id, CustomB__c, Field1__c, Field2__c FROM Customc__c WHERE CustomB__c =: custARecord.CustomB__c];

        return cc1;
    }
```

You can modify the initial for loop above to put create the map that you need to create of CustomBIds to CustomCIds since there can be a many to one relationship between them.

```
        map<Id,Id>bIdToCId = new map<Id,Id>();
        list<Id>custCIds = new list<id>();
        Integer i = 0;
        Id tempBId = new Id();
        Id tempCId = new Id();

        for(Customc__c customcloop : cc1) {

             tempWrapper.add(new wrapper1(false,customcloop));

             bIdToCId.put(get.customcloop.customB__c,CustCIds);

             If(customcloop.Id != tempCId && customcloop.customB__c != tempBId)
             {
                // clear the list
                custCIds.clear();
                i=0;
             }

             custCIds.Add(customcloop.Id)

             If(i==0){
                 // set temp variables to current iteration values
                 tempBId = customcloop.customB__c;
                 tempCId = customcloop.Id;
             }else if(i!=0 && customcloop.customB__c == tempBId && customcloop.Id != tempCId){
                 tempCId = customcloop.customC__c;                  
             }else if(i!=0 && customcloop.customB__c != tempBId && customcloop.Id != tempCId){
                 tempBId = customcloop.customB__c;
                 tempCId = customcloop.customC__c;
             }
             // iterate value of i
             i++;
        }
```

The above isn't the cleanest way of creating the map and I'm confident someone else has a really slick way of doing it, but this is the way I know how to do it. Once you have the map, you can use it to test to see if there's more than one value of C for every B and map those for when you're creating your D and E records since they should correlate. For every C record related to B, there will be an equivalent E record related to D. The map will preserve that relationship for you when creating those records.

Comment: can you show me an example to how to do this?